# How to make mvnw include local proprietary code in a Spring Boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, war

I have a Spring Boot application that I am trying to compile into a proper WAR file. Using the mvnw script, I am experiencing compilation failures.

The problem is that the company I am working for has a set of proprietary classes and JARs that it wants to use in the Spring Boot 
application. The company is using Eclipse. These proprietary resources are in separate source folders (in the case of the java files) and folders (in the case of the jars). In the IDE we can set the jars to be included in the compilation, and when we compile and run the application as a runnable jar, everything compiles.

Unfortunately, if we want to create a deployment, it doesn't matter whether we are creating a war or a jar, mvnw does not find the company's java or jar files and the compilation fails.

There is no problem creating the WAR file. We make the appropriate changes to the pom file and the main class, and as long as we don't use the company proprietary stuff, mvnw compiles and runs the jar (or it properly creates the WAR which runs well on Tomcat). It is only when we want to use the proprietary code that the mvnw compilation fails.

I amcertain that there has got to be some way to make mvnw include external jars and code in external packages, because surely other companies have proprietary code in jars that they need to include in a Spring Boot application. I just don't know how to do it.

So how does one include such code in a Spring Boot application, such that mvnw will compile it?

Comment: Why is what you're doing so different from what most other commercial enterprises is doing? Most of them have their own "proprietary" code.

Comment: Because that is what my boss wants me to do.

Comment: Most other IT departments that use Maven keep their proprietary artefacts in a local (to the organisation or department) repository manager such as Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: Yes. I told this to my boss over two weeks ago. He apparently ignored my suggestion. He wants a Spring Boot application that integrates with a framework he created, and knows nothing about Maven and has no real interest in using it beyond compiling Spring Boot code! The man is tying my hands behind my back and is blaming me when the compile doesn't work. I am going to have to find a different approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create the WAR file.

In Eclipse, I found that if I do an export to the WAR file, the IDE actually compiles everything, including the Maven dependencies and any other defined source files. The resulting WAR has everything needed to run the application.

Having succeeded in doing this, I have run into another problem, which I will describe in another question.